# izpack installer customize uninstaller

Tags: java, izpack, izpanel

I have created installer and uninstaller using izpack. The problem I am facing is when I unisntall it remove everything I have installed. I would like to customise my uninstaller according to my configuration because I need to keep fee files and remove the rest when I run my unisntaller. As long as I have understand and study about izpack, the default behaviour of unistaller is, it remove everything what installer has install.
So is there any way we can customise uninstaller and how.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define  **uninstall=no** under your pack tag, the value of uninstaller attribute give you freedom to choose your pack attach with uninstaller or separate it. Following is the sample code for this:

```
<pack name="Client Solution" required="no" uninstall="no">
```

Answer (score -3):

izpack is open source. Get its source and change the uninstaller class.